# does a formula for $a^2 + b^2$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Like we have $a^2 - b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ does it exist for $ a^2 + b^2.$ or not? I know that $(a^3 + b^3)=(a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2).$ Thanks.

Comment: $$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=(a-b)^2+2ab$$ Again, $2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sum of powers formula exists only for odd powers. But if you are willing to go into complex numbers, you can write it as $(a+ib)(a-ib)$. :)

Comment: Uh! What's wrong in $a^6+b^6=(a^2+b^2)(a^4-a^2b^2+b^4)$? Or in $a^4+b^4=(a^2-ab\sqrt{2}+b^2)(a^2+ab\sqrt{2}+b^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2 = a^2-i^2b^2$ = $ (a+ib)(a-ib) $

Comment: The level of the question *almost-almost* makes it plain clear the OP doesn't know complex numbers...

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to *factor* $a^2+b^2$. Well, the answer is that you can't (over the real numbers).

It's simpler if you consider first $x^2+1$. Such a polynomial cannot be factored over the real numbers, because a (proper) factor should have degree $1$, hence a root.

Now, if a formula $a^2+b^2=f(a,b)g(a,b)$ existed, with $f(a,b)$ and $g(a,b)$ some supposed polynomial expressions, we would have, for $a=x$ and $b=1$,
$$
x^2+1=f(x,1)g(x,1)
$$
Oh, well, this means that either $f(x,1)$ or $g(x,1)$ is a constant polynomial, say it's the latter. But then $g(x,1)$ doesn't depend on $x$, which means $g(a,b)$ doesn't depend on $a$. It's not difficult to finish up and prove that this cannot happen unless $g$ is constant.

<sup>*The above is an abridged version of the theorem that factors of homogeneous polynomials are homogeneous.*</sup>

However, “formulas” (better, factorizations) for other even powers *do* exist. For instance
\begin{align}
a^4+b^4&=(a^2-ab\sqrt{2}+b^2)(a^2+ab\sqrt{2}+b^2)\\[6px]
a^6+b^6&=(a^2+b^2)(a^4-a^2b^2+b^4)\\
&=(a^2+b^2)(a^2-ab\sqrt{3}+b^2)(a^2+ab\sqrt{3}+b^2)
\end{align}